# в конце знак вопроса или точка?

Tags: пунктуация

Артур, очень приятно, уточните номер вашего счета.

Comment: Довольно странно выглядит "очень приятно" в сочетании с приказом. Вы уж или выбросьте "очень приятно", или добавьте "пожалуйста".

Answer (score 1):

Точка. Грамматически это предложение - повелительное наклонение, вопросительному знаку там просто нечего делать. Если бы речь шла о фиксации устной речи, то вопросительный знак еще мог бы претендовать на существование - для передачи интонации. Но в деловой переписке это будет совсем непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

Если просьба, то точка. Если вопрос (типа "не уточните ли вы ещё номер счёта?"), то вопросительный знак.